Use Laravel Filament tables inside Wizard
I am trying to use Filament (v3) Wizard to assist creating quotations. on first step, I tried to get all user input, then using afterValidation method, I validated and iserted these into the database (and kept on session some of them).
On the next step, I want to retrieve some records and show them in Filament table, where I will let user interact with them (Edit with popups). final step will show up summary of these two.
what is the best way to achieve this? with example if possible.
Thank you!
I tried using Wizard in Filament, Also tried to create Livewire component but not sure how to show it inside the Wizard ( part of a resource form )
